# JSF View Scope: How to Check if an object is in the view tree

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jsf-2, view

I use Spring + JSF, with the View Scope being managed by Spring. I've noticed that on every request, the view is destroyed and created again, and so any @PostConstruct method are called on every request.

In most pages this is ok, since in that method are just some object initializations (mainly **new** calls).

But in others pages this is a problem because I have to make heavy queries to initialize some lists, and the view behavior calls the initialization method on every request... so any request in the page is veeeeeery slow.

I know that the view scope stores the bean and it's objects in the session and later recover them; so I want to know if there's a way to check if these objects are already stored so I don't need to initialize those heavy objects at every request; just get them from the session.

**UPDATE**

The view scope used is the one implemented here: http://comdynamics.net/blog/109/spring3-jsf2-view-scope/

Comment: Maybe you need to move data that can be reused on these pages to a Session scoped bean and put a method on it that will allow you to reload the data if necessary. Then get the data for your View scoped beans from the Session bean.

Comment: Spring doesn't support, natively, view-scope (only request, session and application). So either you have created your own view-scope implementation or there is no view scope.

Comment: @M.Deinum is right. If you haven't implemented view scope, then that may be causing your problem. See this blog post for information on how to do that: http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/port-jsf-2-0s-viewscope-to-spring-3-0/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers. Sadly i've implemented the view scope, see the update for info. 
I'm skeptic about using a Session Scope just for storing this data, which is used only in this particular page, because it can be hard to track down and remove it from session manually, at least I think... if you have a good way to do it, don't be shamed to share =D

Comment: Why do you need to track it down and remove it from the session manually? When the session expires, it will be removed automatically.

Comment: @LucasP I can't let it die by itself... the query is not a static one, but a parametrized one. For each case the query would get me different results (there is a query for each row in a table on the page prior to this one in question), so I don't see a way, at least now, to check if the query I have in the session is the query I want to show in the page, see? And I don't think that storing each different query in the session is good either...

Comment: @LucasP I finished implementing your suggestion... it works well, thanks. The possible drawbacks, I will handle later. I can't see a button to accept your suggestion, so if you can answer directly, instead of commenting, I would accept your answer. YannicuLar has already answered the same thing you did, but since you did it first, you deserve de accept. Regards!

Comment: I posted an answer. Thanks for allowing me to do that to get the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move data that can be reused on these pages to a Session scoped bean and put a method on it that will allow you to reload the data if necessary. Then get the data for your View scoped beans from the Session bean. By going this route, you should only be retrieving the data from the database when you need fresh data by calling your reload method on the session bean.

I really don't see another solution to your problem. If you want to persist data beyond the view scope, you either need a session scoped bean or a singleton. Since you should not store session specific data in a singleton bean, you are left with using a session bean.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely put your Query-heavy processes into a SessionScoped Bean.

Then You can use a reference from the ViewScoped beans to the SessionScopedBean, by using @ManagedProperty

Additionally, you can alter your html code to reference the sessionScoped bean properties directly.

If the query, or tree initialization has to be reset after a specific Action (e.g. when you are deleting or adding objects that affect the Tree), or After visiting a Page, then you could move your initialization code into a 'refresh' function. By any means, avoid heavy initializations , queries and large Data handling, in the PostConstruct of ViewScoped or RequestScoped Beans

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i would upvote it if I had enough reputation.